# CSS Animated Radial Graph overflow after animation SVG

Tags: html, css

I've encountered a problem when using the css disarray function. The "front" circle clips over after animation has finished and doesnt "Start" at origin point of the animation. After the animation has completed, the filled stroke clips back past the origin point. Can someone Please help me out - I've tried reading up on SVG elements and have fiddled with the code for a few hours now and I still cant get it to animate properly.

Thank you so much for your support. Here is the code I am working with.

```css
.radial-graph-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 2.4rem;
}

.radial-graph-container .chart-container .back {
  stroke: #101114;
  stroke-width: 10;
}

.radial-graph-container .chart-container .front {
  stroke: #94d82d;
  stroke-width: 15;
  stroke-dasharray: 210;
  /* Works fine with values above 300 */
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.front {
  animation: fill 1s reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="radial-graph-container">
  <svg width="200" height="200" class="chart-container">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" class="back" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" class="front" fill="none" />
      <g class="graph-center-txt">
        <text
        x="100"
        y="100"
          alignment-baseline="central"
          text-anchor="middle"
          id="percentage-social-media-usage"
        >
          42%
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  <p class="graph-info-txt">
    Description Text Here
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roy for the edit! Appreciate it! :D

Comment: Please note that CSS comments and JavaScript comments are not interchangeable, I changed your single-line `// <comment>` comment in CSS to the required format of `/* <comment>*/`, since that didn't seem to be the problem (though it did break your demo when it was converted into a snippet, I think that was incidental though). Also, your snippet doesn't reproduce the problem you describe; where is the `.front` element that seems to be the only thing animated?

Comment: Sorry, Forgot to edit the class ( `Front-ecom-sales` to `Front` ) @DavidThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation part was missing: (the `@keyframes` section)

```css
.radial-graph-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 2.4rem;
}

.radial-graph-container .chart-container .back {
  stroke: #101114;
  stroke-width: 10;
}

.radial-graph-container .chart-container .front {
  stroke: #94d82d;
  stroke-width: 15;
  stroke-dasharray: 210;
  /* Works fine with values above 300 */
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.front {
  animation: fill 1s reverse;
}

@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    r: 90;
  }
  100% {
    r: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="radial-graph-container">
  <svg width="200" height="200" class="chart-container">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" class="back" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" class="front" fill="none" />
      <g class="graph-center-txt">
        <text
        x="100"
        y="100"
          alignment-baseline="central"
          text-anchor="middle"
          id="percentage-social-media-usage"
        >
          42%
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  <p class="graph-info-txt">
    Description Text Here
  </p>
</div>
```